# Boundedness of sequence $ \{||T_n || \} $ in Banach space.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, linear-transformations

I take a new course Funcional analiysis, and I need to prove:

Let $E$ and $F$ Banach spaces and  $T_n (n = 1,2,...)$ linear continuous operators from $E$ in $F$. Suppose that  for all $x \in E$ and for all $f \in  F^*$ sequence of numbers $ \{f (T_n x) \}$ is bounded.
 Then  sequence  $ \{||T_n || \} $ is bounded.
 Where $ F^* $ denotes dual space.
Could anyone help me?

Comment: What have you done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straight application of Banach Steinhauss.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thank you.